# Ohm: how to drop a column/attribute?

Tags: ohm

There's an attribute that I no longer need, and I would like to drop it. I can't seem to simply remove the attribute from my model code, because there is an error when I load the instance. It complains that the `myattrib=` method does not exist. I guess it complains because Ohm sees the key in the database, but the `attribute :myattrib` does not exist in the model code.

How do I delete the column/attribute through Ohm, before I change my code and remove `attribute :myattrib`?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but [this](https://github.com/soveran/ohm/issues/70) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me: `Model.key[:myattrib].del`

found it here: http://ohm.keyvalue.org/Ohm/Model.html#delete-instance_method